# neo4j cypher - how to find all nodes that have a relationship to list of nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes- named "options". "Users" choose these options. I need a chpher query that works like this:

retrieve users who had chosen all the options those are given as a list.

```
MATCH (option:Option)<-[:CHOSE]-(user:User) WHERE  option.Key IN ['1','2','2'] Return user
```

This query gives me users who chose option(1), option(2) and option(3) and also gives me the user who only chose option(2).

What I need is only the users who chose all of them -option(1), option(2) and option(3).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For an all cypher solution (don't know if it's better than Chris' answer, you'll have to test and compare) you can collect the `option.Key` for each user and filter out those who don't have a `option.Key` for each value in your list

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:CHOSE]->(opt:Option)
WITH u, collect(opt.Key) as optKeys
WHERE ALL (v IN {values} WHERE v IN optKeys)
RETURN u
```

or match all the options whose keys are in your list and the users that chose them, collect those options per user and compare the size of the option collection to the size of your list (if you don't give duplicates in your list the user with an option collection of equal size has chosen all the options)

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:CHOSE]->(opt:Option)
WHERE opt.Key IN {values}
WITH u, collect(opt) as opts
WHERE length(opts) = length({values}) // assuming {values} don't have duplicates
RETURN u
```

Either should limit results to users connected with all the options whose key values are specified in {values} and you can vary the length of the collection parameter without changing the query.

Comment: The second aproach is better i think. Because user's choises may be very huge but option list will be at most like 20 or something. Thanks. Actually both answers is ok. I will use the one which will higher performance.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of options is limited, you could do:

```
MATCH 
    (user:User)-[:Chose]->(option1:Option),
    (user)-[:Chose]->(option2:Option),
    (user)-[:Chose]->(option3:Option)
WHERE
    option1.Key = '1'
    AND option2.Key = '2'
    AND option3.Key = '3'
RETURN
    user.Id
```

Which will only return the user with all 3 options.

It's a bit rubbishy as obviously you end up with 3 lines where you have 1, but I don't know how to do what you want using the `IN` keyword.

If you're coding against it, it's pretty simple to generate the `WHERE` and `MATCH` clause, but still - not ideal. :(

**EDIT - Example**

Turns out there is some string manipulation going on here (!), but you can always cache bits. Importantly - it's using `Params` which would allow neo4j to cache the queries and supply faster responses with each call.

```
public static IEnumerable<User> GetUser(IGraphClient gc)
{
    var query = GenerateCypher(gc, new[] {"1", "2", "3"});
    return query.Return(user => user.As<User>()).Results;
}


public static ICypherFluentQuery GenerateCypher(IGraphClient gc, string[] options)
{
    ICypherFluentQuery query = new CypherFluentQuery(gc);
    for(int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
        query = query.Match(string.Format("(user:User)-[:CHOSE]->(option{0}:Option)", i));

    for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
    {
        string paramName = string.Format("option{0}param", i);
        string whereString = string.Format("option{0}.Key = {{{1}}}", i, paramName);
        query = i == 0 ? query.Where(whereString) : query.AndWhere(whereString);
        query = query.WithParam(paramName, options[i]);
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: my option list will be dynamic. so i don't know the actual size of option list.

Comment: What are you going to be using to interact with the server going on? programmatically I think you might end up being limited to generating `Where` and `Match` statements.

Comment: I'm using .Net Web Api. So the request will be as a json option id list. On server i use Neo4jClient

Comment: So you could easily do a loop through the option IDs and create the match / where clauses via the neo4jclient api (that is if no-one comes up with a Cypher example)

Comment: So you mean i should create a dynamic cypher with string concats etc. Ok i will try. But is it right way?

Comment: No - you don't need to use string concats, I'll edit my answer and add an example...

Comment: Thanks Chris. It solved my problem. If query performance is ok, then everything is ok.

Comment: Instead of matching, and then feeding through the WHERE clause, you can do MATCH (user:User) WHERE (user)-[:CHOSE]->(:Option { Key: '1' }) AND (user)-[:CHOSE]->(:Option { Key: '2' }) AND (user)-[:CHOSE]->(:Option { Key: '3' }) RETURN user. That is much easier to generate.

Answer (score 2):

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:CHOSE]->(option:Option) 
WHERE option.key IN ['1', '2', '3']
WITH user, COUNT(*) AS num_options_chosen
WHERE num_options_chosen = LENGTH(['1', '2', '3'])
RETURN user.name
```

This will only return users that have relationships with all the Options with the given keys in the array. **This assumes there are not multiple [:CHOSE] relationships between users and options.** If it is possible for a user to have multiple [:CHOSE] relationships with a single option, you'll have to add some conditionals as necessary.

I tested the above query with the below dataset:

```
CREATE (User1:User {name:'User 1'}),
       (User2:User {name:'User 2'}),
       (User3:User {name:'User 3'}),

       (Option1:Option {key:'1'}),
       (Option2:Option {key:'2'}),
       (Option3:Option {key:'3'}),
       (Option4:Option {key:'4'}),

       (User1)-[:CHOSE]->(Option1),
       (User1)-[:CHOSE]->(Option4),

       (User2)-[:CHOSE]->(Option2),
       (User2)-[:CHOSE]->(Option3),

       (User3)-[:CHOSE]->(Option1),
       (User3)-[:CHOSE]->(Option2),
       (User3)-[:CHOSE]->(Option3),
       (User3)-[:CHOSE]->(Option4)
```

And I get only 'User 3' as the output.

Comment: Thanks Nicole, it is a different that jjaderberg' answer. But it is ok.

Comment: Ah, he must've submitted that while I was typing mine up. Definitely a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

For shorter lists, you can use path predicates in your `WHERE` clause:

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE (user)-[:CHOSE]->(:Option { Key: '1' })
AND   (user)-[:CHOSE]->(:Option { Key: '2' })
AND   (user)-[:CHOSE]->(:Option { Key: '3' })
RETURN user
```

Advantages:

- Clear to read
- Easy to generate for dynamic length lists

Disadvantages:

- For each different length, you will have a different query that has to be parsed and cached by Cypher. Too many dynamic queries will watch your cache hit rate go through the floor, query compilation work go up, and query performance go down.