# Neo4j/Cypher - find nodes that link to all given nodes - the right way?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to filter nodes that link to all given nodes.

I've tried this query which returns every page that has one of `['passionate', 'eye', 'ear']` :

```
MATCH (includeWord:Word) WHERE includeWord.Text IN ['passionate', 'eye', 'ear']
MATCH (p:Page)-[:CONTAINS]->(includeWord:Word)
// WHERE p LINKS TO ALL includeWord AT LEAST ONCE ?
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

This query didn't do the job either :

```
MATCH (p:Page)-[:CONTAINS]->(includeWord:Word)
WHERE includeWord.Text = 'passionate'
AND includeWord.Text = 'eye'
AND includeWord.Text = 'ear'
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

And programmatically speaking it's sort of ugly and unsecure, and I'm sure some of you out there know a better answer.

Maybe something like

```
MATCH (p:Page)-[:CONTAINS]->(includeWord:Word)
WHERE includeWord.Text IN_ALL ['passionate', 'eye', 'ear']
RETURN DISTINCT p
```

?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops,

I found this question [neo4j cypher - how to find all nodes that have a relationship to list of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092163/neo4j-cypher-how-to-find-all-nodes-that-has-a-relationship-to-list-of-nodes) :

And for my query it works perfectly.

It looks like this :

```
MATCH (p:Page)-[:CONTAINS]->(word:Word)
WITH p, collect(word.Text) as words
WHERE ALL (v IN ['passionate', 'eye', 'ear'] WHERE v IN words)
RETURN p
```

It need a bit of reading before understanding !

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually a bit surprised that that second query works.  It's my understanding that a `MATCH` in cypher works by considering one subgraph at a time, so that would mean that it's impossible for any given `:Word` to have a `Text` that is both `'passionate'` and `'eye'` at the same time.  I would expect that you would need to do something like:

```
MATCH
  (p:Page),
  p-[:CONTAINS]->(word1:Word),
  p-[:CONTAINS]->(word2:Word),
  p-[:CONTAINS]->(word3:Word)
WHERE
  word1.Text = 'passionate',
  word2.Text = 'eye',
  word3.Text = 'ear'
RETURN p
```

Obviously that's a more complicated query, though...

Comment: Hem the second one is not Working ! 
Let me correct that ! (thanks)