# Neo4j cypher for all nodes connected to list of values, get sum of relationship parameters

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, nosql

So I'm still learning how to access relationship parameters, I've found several ways to access different aspects of what I'm looking for but can't seem to piece it together.

[neo4j cypher - how to find all nodes that have a relationship to list of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092163/neo4j-cypher-how-to-find-all-nodes-that-have-a-relationship-to-list-of-nodes)

I am getting closer, but can't figure out how to sum a collection and check for length.

```
MATCH (album:Album)-[r]->(tags:Word)
WHERE tags.name IN ['alpha', 'bravo']
WITH album, COLLECT(tags) as tags, COLLECT(r.weight) as weight
RETURN album, tags, weight
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use SUM(r.weight) yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution to avoid the COLLECTION issue, apparently anywhere that you collect you can also sum.  I'm learning though and enjoying the process!

```
MATCH (album:Album)-[r]->(tags:Word) 
WHERE tags.name IN ['alpha', 'bravo']
WITH album, COLLECT(tags) as tags, SUM(r.weight) as weight
WHERE LENGTH(tags) = LENGTH(['alpha', 'bravo'])
RETURN album, tags, weight ORDER BY weight ASC LIMIT 10;
```